# Getting error 'Objects are not valid as a React child' when mapping over imported object that points to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in another file that I import and map over in a separate component. One of the properties that is being mapped over, called `component`, is a reference to another separate component.

I'm trying to get the component to render, but it's throwing the error below and in the title:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {component}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I've looked around and haven't managed to find quite what I'm looking for. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

I export the array like this:

```
import Component1 from "./Component1";
import Component2 from "./Component2";

export default [{ component: Component1 }, { component: Component2 }];
```

And in my component, I try to render these components as,

```
export default function App() {
  return <>{dict.map(({ component }) => component)}</>;
}
```

I've tried doing something like.

```
export default [{ component: <Component1 /> }, { component: <Component2 /> }];
```

But that doesn't even compile.

I guess another option would be to create an object in my `App` component. Something like,

```
const componentMap = {
  Component1: <Component1 />,
  Component2: <Component2 />,
}
```

and change up my `dict` object as,

```
export default [{ component: 'Component1' }, { component: 'Component2' }];
```

I'm wondering why my current approach is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: unruffled-dewdney-qid27]

Comment: You’re returning the component function in App. Try <component />

Comment: I've tried that as well, doesn't work

Comment: Can you try making it `Component` as `component` isn't a native element. To make sure react recognize it as a component you need to make first letter capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just returning the functions but to render the JSX you need to do:

```
export default function App() {
  return <>{dict.map(({ component: Component }) => <Component />)}</>;
}
```

`Note:` Make first letter capital as `component` is not a native element which would throw error.